# How to show keyboard on iOS 8 Today Extension?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I am writing a today extension and I am presenting Social View controller in today's view. the view is presented with a cursor but keyboard does not appear. How to make it appear just like when it appears in a normal app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 8 Today extensions don't support keyboard input.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1